# can we recognize statusbar already have notification icon in android?

Tags: android

i want display multiple notification in single icon

Comment: its hard to resist not to down vote for copy the topic into the question body...

Comment: ok, now you got a down vote, because you also missed the second chance: that is not a specific question but here comes my non specific answer: Feel free to do it!

Comment: to stick with the topic "yes we can" would be even better ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the documentation to the Notification class:

[Notification.number](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#number)

If you set for example

```
myNotification.number = 10
```

then a overlay will be displayed on your notification icon in the status bar showing the value of the `number` variable

Actually it looks like that:

[image]

Comment: i know this...but i am using multiple notification...for this it shows icon per notification